# How to remove multiple tags from a text file using python's regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, tags, findall

Newbie here! I am using Python 3.8.3 and am trying to remove tags from the attached text file  [listfile.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V3s8w8a3NQvex91EdOhdC9rQtCAOElpm/view)

I want to extract 3 lists - titles, publication dates, and main text of the articles and remove the tags. In the code below, I have been able to remove the tags from the titles and publication dates. However, I am not able to properly remove all tags from the main texts. In the file, the main text starts with the tag `<div class="story-element story-element-text">` and ends before the next <h1 class tag.

Any help in extracting this part of the text would be highly appreciated!! The article text is in a non-English script, but all the html tags are in English.

```
#opening text file which contains newspaper article information scraped off website using beautifulsoup
with open('listfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as my_file:
    text = my_file.read()
    print(text)  

#removing tags and generating list of newspaper article titles    
titles = re.findall('<h1.*?>(.*?)</h1>', text)
print(titles) 

#removing tags and generating list of newspaper article publication dates 
dates = re.findall('<div class=\"storyPageMetaData-m__publish-time__19bdV\"><span>(.*?)</span>', text)
print(dates)

#removing tags and generating list containing main text of articles. This is where the code is incorrect
bodytext= re.findall('<div class=\"story-element story-element-text\">(.*?)</div>', text)
print(bodytext)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the wrong tool,
I recommend you use [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) instead; You will love it I promise .

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
raw_html = "YOUR RAW HTML"
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "html.parser")
titles = [h1_tag.text for h1_tag in soup.select('h1')]
dates = [span_tag.text for span_tag in soup.select('div.storyPageMetaData-m__publish-time__19bdV > span')]
bodytext = [div_tag.text for div_tag in soup.select('div.story-element.story-element-text')]
```

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you! This code works for titles and dates but is not getting me all of the bodytext. In the file, the body text starts at the first instance of div.story-element.story-element-text and ends right before the next h1 tag. Is there someway we can modify the code?

Comment: So for example, with bodytext[0], I am getting only the first paragraph of the first article, not all of the first article. With bodytext[1], I am getting the second paragraph of the first article, but I should be getting the second article, right?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not familiar with how regex is set up in python, but this works in JavaScript*

If you'd still like to use RegEx, use this to capture the h1 tags in the text file.  `<h1(.*?)</h1>`

``